# Getting result of a function in another function of the same class

Tags: python, function, twisted

I am getting a litle problem with my code in python 3.7 : I woul like to compare the result i'm getting from my query in the first function (getResult(self, result)) with the query in my 'insertMetersCount()' function. How could i use this?

I know how heritage into differents classes works but not for the functions

```
from twisted.enterprise import adbapi
from twisted.internet import task
import logging
from datetime import datetime
from twisted.internet import reactor


class MetersCount():

    def getTotalMeters(self):
        log.info("Select operation in Database.")
        getMetersQuery = """ SELECT count(met_id) as totalMeters FROM meters WHERE DATE(met_last_heard) = DATE(NOW()) """

        return dbpool.runQuery(getMetersQuery).addCallback(self.getResult).addErrback(self.errorGetQuery)

    def getResult(self, result):
        print ("Receive Result : ")
        print (result)
        # general purpose method to receive result from defer.
        return result

    def errorGetQuery(self,result):
        print ("error received", result)
        return result

    def insertMetersCount(self):
        log.info("Insert operation in Database.")
        insertMetersQuery = """ INSERT INTO meter_count (mec_datetime, mec_count)  VALUES (NOW(), %s)""" % (self.getResult(result)) 
        return dbpool.runQuery(insertMetersQuery).addCallback(self.getResult)

    def checkDB(self):
        self.getTotalMeters()
        self.insertMetersCount()

a= MetersCount()

a.checkDB()

reactor.run()
```

Thats what the error I'm getting : "NameError: global name 'result' is not defined.

Comment: don't you have to give the getResult method in this line:   "return dbpool.runQuery(insertMetersQuery).addCallback(self.getResult)" the result as an argument? Which points to the fact that a getter does not take the return as an argument.

Comment: Please update your question with the full error Traceback.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to stackoverflow.  In the future, try posting a complete code example.  Something someone could run and reproduce the problem you're having.  Also, post the complete error you receive and explain what you expected to happen instead.

You need to pass `result` to `insertMetersCount`.  You can also give it a better name while you're at it and stop using `getResult` which is basically just the identity function plus some logging.  Also, don't interpolate values into SQL.  That's how you create SQL injection vulnerabilities.  You'll have to find the right param style for the DB library you're using.  I've left "%s" but it might be "?" or "\1" or something else.

```
    def insertMetersCount(self, meters_count):
        log.info("Insert operation in Database.")
        insertMetersQuery = """ INSERT INTO meter_count (mec_datetime, mec_count)  VALUES (NOW(), %s)"""
        return dbpool.runQuery(
            insertMetersQuery, [meters_count]
        )
```

Then call the method with the necessary argument.  You can do this with the regular `Deferred` API:

```
    def checkDB(self):
        d = self.getTotalMeters()
        d.addCallback(self.insertMetersCount)
        return d
```

Or with `inlineCallbacks`:

```
    from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks

    @inlineCallbacks
    def checkDB(self):
        meters_count = yield self.getTotalMeters()
        yield self.insertMetersCount(meters_count)
```

These both arrange for exactly the same thing to happen.  They're just two different APIs for doing so.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working like expected 
P.S : Sorry for only posting a part of my code but on the top of it, i have my db connection informations which I have to keep secret because i'm working on a real enterprise db.

Comment: One shudders to think.